# javascript/backbone constructor function wrapped in bracket

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

js newbie here. What does these mean:

```
var a = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
  //..bunch of methods
}));
```

Is it a short hand for define the class first, and then create an instance with new? And why is it viable by just wrapping with the bracket? I might be wrong but I don't believe it's the same as`(function(){})()` If it's the same please help me understand, thanks

edit:

To add that this was seen from backbone code, but I was not sure whether this was a backbone or a js syntax question.

Comment: `.extend` is not a standard thing in Javascript. You need to read the code of whatever defined it to see what it does.

Comment: Hi,  u r right, it was from backbone code. I was not sure whether this question belongs to js or backbone,  and assumed that it was from js syntax. Thanks for the reminder and I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. If we talk in C++/Java terms then it's same as creating a class first and then creating the object.

The code you mentioned above is equivalent to :

```
var myRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  //..bunch of methods
});

var a = new myRouter();
```

As per my understanding the brackets were used to ensure that "new" keyword gets applied to the var (myRouter here) returned by router extend and not to the router extend function itself.

Hope it helps.